# Which would be better? 'Last two weeks' or 'Take two weeks'

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Sorry I will not able to check the attached reports because I have an important task to fulfill and that task might last two weeks.

What it is better to say, 'last two weeks' or 'take two weeks'?

Comment: You should probably not immediately accept the first answer you get!  Wait and see if there are more answers - the first one is not always right.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should definitely say '**last**'. As defined on **Dictionary**;

> '**occurring** or coming after all others, as in **time, order, or place**'

The other way describing, using '**take**', *means somewhat lazy*, whereas '**last**' means you will be continuously be working on said reports.

Comment: What do you mean "means somewhat lazy"?  *Take two weeks* means nothing like that to this US English speaker.

Comment: When you say take, you mean that you will do it SOMEWHERE between 2 weeks, whereas 'last' would mean you are continuously making progress (working hard). Hope this clears it up.

Comment: When somebody tells me that something will take two weeks to complete, I interpret that as requiring two weeks to complete, not that they will do it somewhere in that time span.

Comment: British English here, you shouldn't dislike just because of the cultural differences. I'm talking about how it would be seen in a professional workplace in the UK, and he can adapt it over to the US if that is where he is located.

Comment: If it's a culturally different thing, then that's fine, but we should also note in answers that the answer may be culturally specific.  As a US English speaker, if somebody says, "It will take two weeks to paint the house properly", then I interpret that to mean "the process of painting the house requires two weeks", not that they will do it somewhere within the two week span.  I would really like to see some confirmation of  your interpretation from other BrE speakers.

Comment: It's exactly the same in British English, despite what the answer says.